# I can not insert data in A TArrayField of a FDTable

Tags: android, arrays, delphi, dataset, append

I insert Data in a FDTable

```
OUMatchFDT.Open ;
OUMatchFDT.Append;
    
OUMatchFDTDay.AsDateTime := Now;
OUMatchFDTTime.AsDateTime := Now;
OUMatchFDTHost.AsString := HostEdit.Text ;
OUMatchFDTGuest.AsString := GuestEdit.Text;  
    
// But When I try to insert data in the arrayField 
// OUMatchFDTHostlastSix : TarrayField
   
      
OUMatchFDTHostlastSix[0].AsInteger:= 2;
    
// or
    
OUMatchFDTHostlastSix.Fields.Fields[0].AsString  := '2';
```

I take an error for the TArrayField. `OUMatchFDT:List index out of bounds(0)`

I try to insert data in a FDTable but I meet problem with the TArrayFielfd

Comment: You have misunderstood what FieldValues is.
Read up on the documentation and then look over your code.
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.FieldValues

Comment: Thank you. I had misunderstood what FieldValues was. I edit my question.